# Find all complex numbers $z$ satisfying $|z+2i| = |z-2|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am facing a small math problem. I need to find all complex numbers $z$ satisfying the equation $|z+2i| = |z-2|$.

I'd be very grateful if someone could "teach" me how to solve this one.

Best regards,
Janno

Comment: One way would be to rephrase the question as "Find all points $z$ on complex plane such that distance from $z$ to $-2i$ equals distance from $z$ to $2$".

Comment: These are precisely the points on the perpendicular bisector of the segment $[-2i,2]$

Comment: If you don't want to go the geometric route (which was my instinct) then write $z=a+bi$ and, squaring both sides, you get: $a^2+(b+2)^2=(a-2)^2+b^2$. Solve, and you get a linear equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with $$z=x+iy$$ we get $$x^2+(y+2)^2=(x-2)^2+y^2$$ simplifying this we get $$y=-x$$

Answer (score 2):

your complex number should be on the perpendicular bisector of *-**2**i* and **2** as you can see if you think them as points of plane.

Answer (score 0):

When $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

1. $$\left|\text{z}+2i\right|=\left|\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right)+2i\right|=\left|\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\left(2+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]\right)i\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\left(2+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]\right)^2}$$
2. $$\left|\text{z}-2\right|=\left|\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right)-2\right|=\left|\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]-2\right)+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right|=\sqrt{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]-2\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$$

So:

$$\left|\text{z}+2i\right|=\left|\text{z}-2\right|\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\left(2+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]\right)^2}=\sqrt{\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]-2\right)^2+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$$